# Does regex have to be a "pattern/calculation" instead of exact match?

Tags: java, regex, string

I wonder if "exact match" can be included in regex, or broader definition of regex?

If I have a code like:

```
find.equals("match")
```

or

```
find.matches("match")
```

Do we actually include the "match" as a kind of regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, regex stands for regular expression, at its generally used to match a pattern instead of exact match.
But you can do exact match with it too like to match something similar to find.equals("match") you can use

```
find.matches("^match$")
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to include the `^` or the `$`. See [regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#string)

Comment: He asked, to do exact match, so i gave him an exact match.

Comment: yes, see the aforementioned link. Without the `^` and `$`, it is already an exact match. `String#matches(String)` attempts to match the **whole** regex.

Comment: But it will match for words "matcher" "matches" "wmatches" and everything. How can you call it an exact match.